# How to make vscode autocomplete props that are spread in a React functional component

Tags: reactjs, react-native, visual-studio-code

I have a functional component in react native. It goes like this:

```
export const Row = ({ children, style, ...props }) => (
  <View
    style={[{ flexDirection: "row", alignItems: "center" }, style]}
    {...props}
  >
    {children}
  </View>
);
```

I am using it like this:

```
const App = () => {
  return (
    <Row>
      <Text>Hello</Text>
    </Row>
  );
};

export default App;
```

How can I enable autocomplete of vscode while using Row component. For example, I want to use onMagicTap that is in View, how can see the autocomplete in Row. I have spread the props in View but I can't see the autocomplete. Any solution to this?

PS. I am use JS, not TS

Answer (score 1):

you can try vs-code extensions, one I use "React Native Snippet"

Comment: How would that enable me to autocomplete props like `onLayout` or `onResponderEnd`

Comment: it will suggest you when you start typing or do ctrl + space (in mac : cmd + space) 

try this <Text style={{ <try here>}}> 

Note: Text should be imported from react-native